# Send message to BBM group?

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

I want my application to send a message to a BBM group.

Comment: It's imp for dudes...
help me....

Comment: What have you tried?  Please include references to specific code snippets you have tried to use.

Comment: I am not able to find any example or way to get BBM group...
So i need some Example for that...

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't a way for your application to specify the BBM Group to share text or an image with.  You can provide the text or image to share and invoke to share over a BBM Group.  When you do the BBM Group picker appears where the user selects the group they want to post to.  Here's some sample QML that shows how to post some text to a BBM Group.

```
InvokeActionItem {
title: "Share Text Over BBM Group"
query {
    mimeType: "text/plain"
    invokeTargetId: "sys.bbgroups.sharehandler"
    invokeActionId: "bb.action.SHARE"
    data: "This is some text to share in a group."
}
```